# No Persistence provider for EntityManager in JPA, Maven, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am currently new to Maven and as usual, got stuck in a very minor error.
I am using Netbeans IDE for my project. 
So, I have created a simple java project that tries to connect and create a table in the Mysql using maven. I have also gone through each and every solution that was available here(Stack overFlow) in such similar questions that were asked by other coders as well but none helped me.

Now, whenever I run my project it shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named JPA.student
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at JPA.App.main(App.java:20)
```

Here is my Persistence.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

```
<persistence-unit name="com.mycompany.mavenjava.java" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>JPA.student</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vikas" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="vikas" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="Vikas@137" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is my pom.xml file :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.mavenJava</groupId>
    <artifactId>JPA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Your crucial help would be very precious.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With what server?, how are you running the app?

Comment: @rekiem87 It's a simple java project with maven, JPA and hibernate. So I am directly running it from the simple run button at the top of the IDE. It isn't a web app that I need a server for it.

Comment: Ok, so, whats the Maven output when you run the app?, the build should import all the pom libraries to your project

Comment: @rakiem87  maven output is working fine. It gives 'BUILD SUCCESS'. So  is there anything else that I should look for ?

Comment: @rakiem87 No problem now! I have updated my post, the problem is solved. Read the post for more.  THANKS for your help.

Comment: Nice!, you should add your own correction as an answer and not just an edit, so you can mark it as resolved and be seen and used for others

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved.**
I just came to know that I had kept all of my Java files in a different directory inside src/main/java/FOLDERNAME whereas I should be keeping them inside the directory as declared in the persistence-unit tag (found in persistence.xml file). So I made that change and then it worked ! Now all java files are inside the directory as :
  **JPA/src/main/java/com/mycompany/mavenjava/jpa/(Java files)**

Group-Id : com.mycompany.mavenjava
Artifact-Id : JPA

This directory got created by combining group-Id name & artifact-Id name during project creation.
But anyways it worked! I was almost stuck for 5+ hours in this small error. Such errors come mostly to newbies because they don't have any experience with maven framework and I am also one of them.